# Is there anything like /proc for windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, equivalent, procfs

I'm Curious about 2 things,

1. What is the closest equivalent to /proc that ships with windows
2. Are there any products which add a proc like filesystem to windows?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/ProjFS-Managed-API

Answer (score 3):

1. Task manager
2. [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), giving Windows a Linux environment, certainly allows a Windows program to use `/proc`.

Comment: did't think of cygwin. It notes that it doesn't support everything but /proc/registry looks really cool

Comment: To be more precise, cygwin does not bring linux environment, but POSIX.However, +1

Comment: What's the underlying Windows method used to do something like `/proc/stat`?

Comment: @rkosegi : "/proc" isn't POSIX.

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you explained what your final goal is. What are you trying to do?
For managing processes on windows you have the following options:

1. Windows ships with Task Manager (taskmgr.exe)
2. A better more versatile alternative is a tool called [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
3. You also have the command line utility called tasklist.exe which can perform many tasks.
4. Also there are other ways to interact with processes, including winapi, WMI and so on.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there isn't anything equivalent to /proc in Windows. While there are facilities for getting similar information via Win32_Process (limited in comparison to /proc, e.g. you won't be able to get process memory maps this way) in WMI, windbg or Win32 APIs, Windows does not record this data onto files.