# How to get Windows load values

Tags: java, windows, nio, cpu-usage

I would like using Java to get data from Windows about CPU, RAM, HDD, Network and list of processes(services). How I can get these system values values without using third-party libraries or JNI?

Is there something similar to /proc in Windows where I can get all necessary values and use them?

Comment: What does this question have to do with java 8?

Comment: Isn't this possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use native API's using **JNI**.

You can also use [SIGAR](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar) which is Apache licensed library which does much more then what you are asking for.It has wrapped the native calls in Java API's so that you dont have to know the inner workings of **JNI**.

You can also spawn processes from inside the code to run OS specific commands so that you can collect the system stats e.g. systeminfo |find "Available Physical Memory" or wmic command on windows or Linux cat /proc/meminfo . This can be achieved via java.lang.ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can get everything you want from a single location in the standard java API, but you could use the following classes for some of your requirements:

For the number of processors / processor stats / memory, etc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html\

For information about physical disks and whatnot:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Another, really, really ugly option would be to make platform specific invokations of utilities via a Process object, and parse their output. EG invoke the top command via a process, read and parse its output.

Comment: Are there any text files similar to /proc in Linux?

Comment: I don't believe so. The registry stores most information for windows, and system information is available via task manager or MMC, but as far as im aware, task manager doesnt reference any virtual files like /proc. This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802143/is-there-anything-like-proc-for-windows

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java  Can I read these values from windows registry?

Answer (score 2):

There is **Windows Management Instrumentation API (WMI)** for this kind of stuff. See e.g. .NET bindings here: [MSDN - System.Management Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx)

Older Stack Overflow answer to similar question is available here: [Recommended libraries/howtos for using WMI with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610063/recommended-libraries-howtos-for-using-wmi-with-java)

**Look for newer Java bindings**. There used to be J# as one of the .NET languages that was source-level compatible with Java. So in theory there should not be a big problem to find suitable **Java→.NET→WMI bridge**

This API is very powerful and besides some basic stuff like processes, sound devices, disk drives etc. you can access approximately same set of information that you can get by running `msinfo32.exe`.

So this is not Java-specific answer this is Windows-specific answer. All Windows versions support .NET and .NET can access that information through WMI easily.

For instance list of processes can be accessed easily through [MSDN - System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx)

There used to be special Win32 APIs for native binaries and though still supported they are the history now. Piping output from one command line app to input of another is not the usual way to connect processes. In case this is really needed there is [Microsoft Technet - Scripting with Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx)

I hope this will help you find some solution of your problem

Comment: Can you give me some more information about `newer Java bindings`? If you have opportunity would you show me some basic example?

Comment: @Peter I'm sorry for confusion. By "newer Java bindings" I meant just go through the Java→WMI bindings proposed in the "Recommended libraries.." linked article and check if there is a newer version available as the answer is little bit old. e.g the jWMI is from 2010 so perhaps contact Henry Ranch on his website to ask for newer version or known problems etc. I don't have personal practical experience with using WMI from Java so I will not help you much more (BTW: you can also create PowerShell script (it has full .NET access) and you call it as command line application)

Comment: @Peter quick Google redirected me to http://superuser.com/questions/176624/linux-top-command-for-windows-powershell where you can find more about Linux commands and their PowerShell alternatives..

Answer (score 1):

There are several options for getting system information in Java (the `Runtime` class, the `java.lang.management` package, etc.).

However, this is usually very limited information, and tends not to cover the things you seem to require.

You should consider using a 3rd party solution, such as the following:

- SIGAR - http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar (requires native DLL to be installed)
- OSHI - https://github.com/oshi/oshi

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would suggest you to try JavaSysMon:

https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon

Manage OS processes and get cpu and memory stats cross-platform in Java. So the good thing about it is , its cross-platform.
Currently it supports Mac OS X, Linux, Windows, and Solaris.
So that is a positive. If this can do your work, you can actually use the cross-platform feature for your application.

Maybe its not as good as Sigar, but give it a try.