# Jupyter notebook: memory usage for each notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

The memory on my lab's server (Ubuntu) is constantly filling up due to users never shutting down old notebooks. I would like to get a better idea of how much memory each notebook is taking up. I can summarize (rough) memory usage for all jupyter notebooks run by each user, but I would like to get the total memory usage of each individual notebook so that I can shut down those particular memory hogs (or tell another user to shut his/her's down). I quickly put together the following code to get approx. mem. usage per jupyter kernel, but I don't know how to associate the kernel IDs to a particular notebook.

```py
import os
import pwd
import pandas as pd

UID   = 1
EUID  = 2

pids = [pid for pid in os.listdir('/proc') if pid.isdigit()]

df = []
for pid in pids:
    try:
        ret = open(os.path.join('/proc', pid, 'cmdline'), 'rb').read()
    except IOError: # proc has already terminated
        continue
    
    # jupyter notebook processes
    if len(ret) > 0 and 'share/jupyter/runtime' in ret:
        process = psutil.Process(int(pid))
        mem = process.memory_info()[0] 
           
        # user name for pid
        for ln in open('/proc/%d/status' % int(pid)):
            if ln.startswith('Uid:'):
                uid = int(ln.split()[UID])
                uname = pwd.getpwuid(uid).pw_name

        # user, pid, memory, proc_desc
        df.append([uname, pid, mem, ret])
        
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.columns = ['user', 'pid', 'memory', 'proc_desc']
df
```

Comment: i can't run this.. due to no module found with error `PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:  - pwd`. anyother solution that doesn't require `pwd`. I am on windows server with anaconda python 2.7.

Answer (score 7):

I made some improvements to [sharchaea's script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698718/5292302) for portability and speed.

Mainly, only check ports that notebooks are running on, check different hostname options, improve the kernel process check and check for ipython or jupyter.

```py
import argparse
import re
import subprocess

import pandas as pd
import psutil
import requests
import tabulate

kernel_regex = re.compile(r".+kernel-(.+)\.json")
notebook_regex = re.compile(r"(https?://([^:/]+):?(\d+)?)/?(\?token=([a-z0-9]+))?")


def get_proc_info():
    pids = psutil.pids()

    # memory info from psutil.Process
    df_mem = []

    for pid in pids:
        try:
            proc = psutil.Process(pid)
            cmd = " ".join(proc.cmdline())
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            continue

        if len(cmd) > 0 and ("jupyter" in cmd or "ipython" in cmd) and "kernel" in cmd:
            # kernel
            kernel_ID = re.sub(kernel_regex, r"\1", cmd)

            # memory
            mem = proc.memory_info()[0] / float(1e9)

            uname = proc.username()

            # user, pid, memory, kernel_ID
            df_mem.append([uname, pid, mem, kernel_ID])

    df_mem = pd.DataFrame(df_mem)
    df_mem.columns = ["user", "pid", "memory_GB", "kernel_ID"]
    return df_mem


def get_running_notebooks():
    notebooks = []

    for n in subprocess.Popen(
        ["jupyter", "notebook", "list"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    ).stdout.readlines()[1:]:
        match = re.match(notebook_regex, n.decode())
        if match:
            base_url, host, port, _, token = match.groups()
            notebooks.append({"base_url": base_url, "token": token})
        else:
            print("Unknown format: {}".format(n.decode()))

    return notebooks


def get_session_info(password=None):
    df_nb = []
    kernels = []

    for notebook in get_running_notebooks():
        s = requests.Session()
        if notebook["token"] is not None:
            s.get(notebook["base_url"] + "/?token=" + notebook["token"])
        else:
            # do a get to the base url to get the session cookies
            s.get(notebook["base_url"])
        if password is not None:
            # Seems jupyter auth process has changed, need to first get a cookie,
            # then add that cookie to the data being sent over with the password
            data = {"password": password}
            data.update(s.cookies)
            s.post(notebook["base_url"] + "/login", data=data)

        res = s.get(notebook["base_url"] + "/api/sessions")

        if res.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception(res.json())

        for sess in res.json():
            kernel_ID = sess["kernel"]["id"]
            if kernel_ID not in kernels:
                kernel = {
                    "kernel_ID": kernel_ID,
                    "kernel_name": sess["kernel"]["name"],
                    "kernel_state": sess["kernel"]["execution_state"],
                    "kernel_connections": sess["kernel"]["connections"],
                    # "notebook_url": notebook["base_url"] + "/notebook/" + sess["id"],
                    "notebook_path": sess["path"],
                }
                kernel.update(notebook)
                df_nb.append(kernel)
                kernels.append(kernel_ID)

    df_nb = pd.DataFrame(df_nb)
    del df_nb["token"]
    return df_nb


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Find memory usage.")
    parser.add_argument("--password", help="password (only needed if pass-protected)")

    return parser.parse_args()


def main(password=None, print_ascii=False):
    df_mem = get_proc_info()
    df_nb = get_session_info(password)

    # joining tables
    df = pd.merge(df_nb, df_mem, on=["kernel_ID"], how="inner")
    df = df.sort_values("memory_GB", ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    if print_ascii:
        print(tabulate.tabulate(df, headers=(df.columns.tolist())))
    return df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = vars(parse_args())
    main(args["password"], print_ascii=True)
```

I'll probably continue to make updates to this at this [gist](http://gist.github.com/aiguofer/5b0a5532de84402e4ced0548f4650f2d)

edit: Code has been updated to work with newer versions of Jupyter using token authentication, to leverage only `psutil` making it Windows compatible, and to work on Python 3.

Comment: i can't run this.. due to no module found with error `PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:  - pwd`. anyother solution that doesn't require `pwd`. I am on windows server with anaconda python 2.7.

Comment: @ihightower hmmm, I doubt this will work on Windows. It's getting most of its info about the processes from proc, which is a Unix way of storing data about running processes, services, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802143/is-there-anything-like-proc-for-windows might give you a starting point.

Comment: @ihightower I've updated this to not use `pwd` or `/proc`. Instead it only uses `psutil` which should be portable and work on Windows.

Comment: @aiguofer you should add password=args(["password"]) in your main arguments when you call it in *ifmain*. Otherwise it could be interpreted as the hostname right ?

Comment: @tricky thanks for pointing that out :) I changed the script quite a bit and forgot to change that signature for main. The hostname is now found using `jupyter notebook list` so you don't have to pass it in. I might add the option to run against remote servers using Fabric in the future.

Answer (score 5):

I seemed to have figured out a working solution for my own problem:

```
import os
import pwd
import psutil
import re
import string
import json
import urllib2
import pandas as pd

UID   = 1
EUID  = 2
regex = re.compile(r'.+kernel-(.+)\.json')

pids = [pid for pid in os.listdir('/proc') if pid.isdigit()]

# memory info from psutil.Process
df_mem = []
for pid in pids:
    try:
        ret = open(os.path.join('/proc', pid, 'cmdline'), 'rb').read()
    except IOError: # proc has already terminated
        continue

    # jupyter notebook processes
    if len(ret) > 0 and 'share/jupyter/runtime' in ret:
        # kernel
        kernel_ID = re.sub(regex, r'\1', ret)
        kernel_ID = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, kernel_ID)

        # memory
        process = psutil.Process(int(pid))
        mem = process.memory_info()[0] / float(1e9)


        # user name for pid
        for ln in open('/proc/{}/status'.format(int(pid))):
            if ln.startswith('Uid:'):
                uid = int(ln.split()[UID])
                uname = pwd.getpwuid(uid).pw_name

        # user, pid, memory, kernel_ID
        df_mem.append([uname, pid, mem, kernel_ID])

df_mem = pd.DataFrame(df_mem)
df_mem.columns = ['user', 'pid', 'memory_GB', 'kernel_ID']


# notebook info from assessing ports
df_nb = []
for port in xrange(5000,30000):
    sessions = None
    try:
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:{}/api/sessions'.format(port)
        sessions = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
    except urllib2.URLError:
        sessions = None

    if sessions:
        for sess in sessions:
            kernel_ID = str(sess['kernel']['id'])
            notebook_path = sess['notebook']['path']
            df_nb.append([port, kernel_ID, notebook_path])

df_nb = pd.DataFrame(df_nb)
df_nb.columns = ['port', 'kernel_ID', 'notebook_path']


# joining tables
df = pd.merge(df_nb, df_mem, on=['kernel_ID'], how='inner')
df.sort(['memory_GB'], ascending=False)
```