# Interact with password protected Jupyter /api

Tags: authentication, urllib2, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

A friend is trying to run a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39988047/1815486) to check which notebooks are using the most memory, but their server is password protected. I'm trying to figure out how to configure authentication using `urllib2` since I don't believe there is a username, only a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @aiguofer answer did not work for me because jupyter now uses '_xsrf' in cookie. The follwoing woked for me:

```
s = requests.Session()
url='http://127.0.0.1:8888/login/'
resp=s.get(url)
xsrf_cookie = resp.cookies['_xsrf']

params={'_xsrf':xsrf_cookie,'password': password}
s.post(url, data=params)
```

After that `s` can be used to call the apis.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I had fixed this in my code but forgot about this SO post/answer.

Comment: @aiguofer
It seems that this does not work in new versions of jupyter anymore :( Do you happen to know any updated approach?

Comment: unfortunately I haven't used jupyter notebooks in years so I haven't kept up with it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are some changes with new version. url '/login' does not work for me, I need to add `next` parameters

```
url='http://localhost:8050/login?next=%2F'
```

For the login request. The rest just like [Hassan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55568762/3444923)

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the notebook code and through some trial and error, I figured out how to do this (and I switched to using `requests`).

I can't guarantee that this is the best way to do it, but it certainly worked for me. I actually set my vars elsewhere in the code but included here for completeness

```py
import requests

hostname = '127.0.0.1'
port = '8888'
password = 'mypassword'

base_url = 'http://{0}:{1}/'.format(hostname, port)
h = {}
if password:
    r = requests.post(base_url + 'login', params={
        'password': password
    })
    h = r.request.headers
sessions = requests.get(base_url + 'api/sessions', headers=h).json()
```

I believe this works because when you hit the `/login` endpoint, it redirects you with the right headers set. I guess `requests` keeps the headers of the redirect, so we can reuse those for the other call. It might be better to extract only the cookies and use those, but this works for now :)

Answer (score 0):

i found when use jupyter put api upload file response 403,

need add "X-XSRFToken" header can solve it..

```
data= json.dumps({
            "name": "test.jpg",
            "path": "path",
            "type":"file",
            "format": "base64",
            "content": "base64 data"
        })

headers["X-XSRFToken"] = xsrf_cookie
s.put(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```