# Error when renaming columns to an existing Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Basically this question is related to: [notebook-memory-usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685825/jupyter-notebook-memory-usage-for-each-notebook), the original post is a bit too old, so I guess it is better to start a new one.

Here is portion of code:

```
def get_proc_info():
    # memory info from psutil.Process
    df_mem = []
    ....
    df_mem = pd.DataFrame(df_mem)
    df_mem.columns = ['user', 'pid', 'memory_GB', 'kernel_ID']
    return df_mem, ports
```

Errors out at `df_mem.columns = ['user', 'pid', 'memory_GB', 'kernel_ID']` as below:

> File "./notebook_mem_usage.py", line 64, in get_proc_info
>       df_mem.columns = ['user', 'pid', 'memory_GB', 'kernel_ID']
>
> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values
>   have 4 elements

It would be appreciated if anyone can shed me more light, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: your `df_mem`  is empty list, and trying to put name for empty dataframe. So you are getting this error.

Comment: You are not renaming columns, you are adding new ones.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the post you linked to your issue? Why do you think they are related?

Comment: Hi @roganjosh, the code is part of the post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns need to exist beforehand before your rename them. Consider an empty dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

print(df.columns)

Index([], dtype='object')
```

You can't fit 4 values in an array of size 0. Therefore, you see `ValueError`. You have a couple of options:

#### Specify columns when instantiating

The `pd.DataFrame` constructor has a `columns` argument:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['user', 'pid', 'memory_GB', 'kernel_ID'])
```

#### Join empty dataframe with one which has columns

Create an empty dataframe and join a new one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=['user', 'pid', 'memory_GB', 'kernel_ID']))
```